# Storing NaN in property list (plist) file

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, foundation

Is it possible to store a NaN in a property list file. I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
     <integer>nan</integer>
</array>
</plist>
```

But Xcode was not able to phrase the file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floats or doubles can be `NaN`s, but an integer can not.

Also not sure if you can store it in a plist file.

However, if you use `NSUInteger` for your integer, you can use a predefined marker like `NSNotFound`, or you can define your own value that you want to reserve for the purpose.

Comment: If you codes the plist by hand (instead of writing it to file in code), type the value -1. NSNotFound is defined as -1, or the same bit pattern as the largest possible unsigned integer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for example a dictionary with a NaN value for the key "A_NaN_Value":

```
<dict>
   <key>A_NaN_Value</key>
   <real>nan</real>
</dict>
```